# Moment converting digit into date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular2-moment

Trying to understand how moment.js is converting a string to date, I've bounced into this issue.

```js
let date = "User has logged in to more than 10 .";
console.log(moment(date)); //output date

let invalid = "User has logged in to more than 10 a";
console.log(moment(invalid)); //output invalid date
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/2.2.0/moment-range.js"></script>
```

can someone explain it to me ??

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqOvEp)

Comment: CodePen link code doesn't work mate

Comment: @GeorgeK, try again.

Comment: I get a couple errors, "Deprecation warning..." and "Log Skipped: Sorry, this log was too large for our console..." I don't suppose this is what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the string `moment` checks whether it is a valid date format, and if not, it falls back to the built-in javascript `Date.parse()` method.

The moment.js docs say:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string
>   matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches
>   the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new
>   Date(string) if a known format is not found.

`Date.parse` does not recognize anything useful in your string until it encounters `10`; it drops the rest. A default date format is assumed, which will depend on your location and language. In my own case, here in the US, the format is `MM/DD`. The result is that the string is parsed to a date of Oct. 1st (10th month, no day specified defaults to the 1st). And then (for Y2K-ish reasons, I suspect) it assumes a year of 2001, since no year is given.

We get the same behavior from javascript's built-in `Date` methods:

```
new Date(Date.parse('User has logged in to more than 10.'))
// Mon Oct 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) <- As printed from Michigan.
```

In your second case, you tried ending the string with `10 a` instead of `10 .` and you will notice the same behavior (`invalid date`) if you pass the same to the built-in `Date` methods.

Comment: Totally agree with you, moment has [strict mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) to prevent this unexpected behaviour. I'm still trying to understand while `Date.parse('10')` is considered a date in 2001.